# Multiple entries containing exact file paths or text file on server containing multiple file paths with a single entry in the database to that file?

Tags: mysql

Here's some background information to help understand my dilemma. I've got a system written in PHP where users can fill out a form, upload a few images and everything gets archived in a .zip, I then have an "Account Page" that echo's a simple table containing a list of all of that specific users uploaded .zip's, the reason I'd need separate filepaths for each and every .zip is because no matter the user, they all need to be in the same single folder on the server for the broader application to work (these .zips are used for a mobile based Package Manager; see [Cydia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia)).

Would the smarter choice be to have every name of each .zip stored in a table on the database with things like the username and user_id tying to each entry, which would result in a few entries being for one user, and a few more being for a different user (depending on upload time), and everything will be unorganized. If I need to enter the database and manually search for a specific user's uploaded .zip's, I'll have to sort them out by user_id.

OR

Would it be more cost effective (in terms of passing data and hardware limitations) to have an XML file or even a plain .txt file on the server with a list of the users uploaded .zip's, and an exact file path pointing to them, and in the database simply have one column tied to the rest of the users information that points to that file containing multiple lines of filepaths?

It's a mouth full I know, and I have no problem achieving either of them as it's well within my skillset and knowledge of PHP & MySQL, I'm just not too sure which is the most secure and the best practice in the industry for this type of system.